# invoking a delegate method of a class by code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

is it possible to invoke a delegate method of a class by code?
In my case I want to invoke the `searchBar:textDidChange:` method in my code!
If yes how would I do that ?

Comment: It's just a method -- there's nothing special about delegate methods.  Invoke it like any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you know exactly how to cook the objects for its parameters.

It is just another method and you can call like

```
[self searchBar:parameter textDidChange:parameter];
```

IMHO, I would say, in this case, searchBar is in better position to pass the objects, rather than you invoke yourself.

Comment: why does this then give me an warning ? `[self searchBar:mysearchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:mysearchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex];` ???

Comment: What warning you are getting?

Comment: actually I do get 2: `Semantic Issue: Instance method '-searchBar:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
` and `'SearchViewController' may not respond to '-searchBar:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:'
`

Comment: Make your searchBar:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange method implementation comes before the method in which you actually call it. When the compiler walks down from top to bottom, it is yet to see this method implementation, hence the warning.